# How to deselect ListViewItem programmatically?

Tags: c#, listview, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I'm stumped with this little problem for a while. The *ListView* under W10 has some strange behavior I cannot understand. Consider a simple list:

```xml
<ListView Name="myList" ItemClick="myList_ItemClick" SelectionChanged="myList_SelectionChanged" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
    <ListView.Items>
        <TextBlock Text="First item"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Second item"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Third item"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Fifth item"/>
    </ListView.Items>
</ListView>
```

and the code behind:

```cs
private void myList_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Clicked item");
    ListView list = sender as ListView;
    ListViewItem listItem = list.ContainerFromItem(e.ClickedItem) as ListViewItem;
    listItem.IsSelected = !listItem.IsSelected;
}

private void myList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Selection changed -> added = {e.AddedItems.Count}, removed = {e.RemovedItems.Count}, currently selected = {myList.SelectedItems.Count}");
}
```

The code above runs very well on W8.1, but on W10 I encounter a problem. Selecting a first item works ok, changing it also, but I cannot deselect an item - listview seems (from debug output) to deselect item and then select it again right away - you can see *SelectionChanged* event fired twice. Here is sample debug output:

[image: Debug Output]

Does somebody know what is going on? How to deselect the item in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming that there's a different order of events going on in UWP. Something like this:

Item not selected -> ItemClick event handler -> Item is selected -> SelectionChanged event -> *Some other event* -> No more SelectionChanged events as that item is already selected.

Item is selected -> ItemClick event handler -> Item is not selected -> SelectionChanged event -> *Some other event* -> SelectionChanged event fires again as the item is no longer selected.

Here's a bit of a dirty trick to make it work:

```
private void myList_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Clicked item");
    ListView list = sender as ListView;
    ListViewItem listItem = list.ContainerFromItem(e.ClickedItem) as ListViewItem;

    if (listItem.IsSelected)
    {
        listItem.IsSelected = false;
        list.SelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.None;
    }
    else
    {
        list.SelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.Single;
        listItem.IsSelected = true;
    }
}
```

EDIT: The behavior for multiple selection already works as expected: the item is deselected on second click. No workarounds needed!

Comment: Thanks. For single item seems to work - also we can ommit `listItem.IsSelected = false;`, the change of *SelectionMode* will do the job. But this trick won't help if we want to make a multi-selection - do you have any idea for that case?

Comment: @Romasz When SelectionMode="Multiple" the default behavior already deselects the item on second click - no tricks are needed. :)

Comment: Yeah, with multiple selection it works. I will have to redesign couple of things. Nevertheless IMO there is something wrong if we are not able to deselect the item in *SingleMode* other that reseting *SelectionMode*. Thank you for help, I will leave this question open for a while, maybe someone is able to explain what is going on with those events.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this is due to an update but this works;

```
 ListViewItem item = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
//Do whatever you need to with item
item.Selected = false;
```

I encountered the same problem and the answer on this page guided me to try the above.

Comment: Something might have changed during time.  Have you tried this with the code from the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the selection in listview

```
listView1.SelectedItems[0].Focused = false;
listView1.SelectedItems[0].Selected = false;
```

[For further details, check this article how to clear selection inside selectedIndex changed event](http://kodecenter.com/article?id=4177f0d8-8a5b-4dde-904b-b06112c23017)

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me in UWP targeting build 17134.

I was trying to deselect on double click. Eventually, I found this:

```cs
ctor () { // wherever you are doing setup
    myList.SelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.Extended;
    myList.DoubleTapped += myList_DoubleTapped;
    myList.SelectionChanged += myList_SelectionChanged;
}

int deselect = 0;
private void myList_DoubleTapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    deselect = (e.PointerDeviceType == PointerDeviceType.Touch) ? 1 : 2;
    MyList.SelectedIndex = -1;
}

private void myList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (deselect > 0)
    {
        myList.SelectedIndex = -1;
        deselect--;
    }
}
```

Using `ListViewSelectionMode.Single` doesn't work. Using a `bool` flag for `deselect` doesn't work.

If you need to clear the selection from an event that is not on the list view (e.g. from a `Button`):

```
deselect = 0;
existingPinList.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

UWP `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`